# How do I use kd-trees for determining string similarity?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, kdtree

I am trying to utilize k-nearest neighbors for the string similarity problem i.e. given a string and a knowledge base, I want to output k strings that are similar to my given string. Are there any tutorials that explain how to utilize kd-trees to efficiently do this k-nearest neighbor lookup for strings? The string length will not exceed more than 20 characters.

Comment: What's your similarity metric between 2 strings ? [scipy.spatial.cKDtree](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html) is fast and solid, good for 20d, but does only Lp metrics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably one of the hottest blog posts I had read a year or so ago: [Levenstein Automata](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Levenshtein-Automata).  Take a look at that article.  It provides not only a description of the algorithm but also code to follow.  Technically, it's not a kd-tree but it's quite related to the string matching and dictionary correction algorithms one might encounter/use in the real world.

He also has another blog post about [BK-trees](http://blog.notdot.net/2007/4/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Part-1-BK-Trees) which are much better at the fuzzy matching for strings and string look ups where there are mispellings.  Here is another resource containing source code for a [BK-tree](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/572156-bk-tree/) (this one I can't verify the accuracy or proper implementation.)

Comment: the Levenshtein Automata is impressive, however, having implemented it, I can only say that the precomputed version quickly explodes (in term of nodes) when the distance grow up. In practice, it's blazing fast to search in a Trie, but the automaton starts becoming really big for a distance of 4 and upwards.

Comment: @Matthieu M. what would you recommend instead?

Comment: I don't have implemented (seriously) any other mechanism, so I don't have any recommendation. If you can live with a maximum distance of `3`, then do use it, otherwise, you'll have to explore on your own, I am afraid :)

Comment: @MatthieuM. what about some nested automatas to allow for example edit distance of up to 3+3.