# Is there a faster way to apply a function instead of using a loop within a loop in python

Tags: python, loops

I am iterating over a file and creating a set of unique "in" strings. I next iterate over a pair of files and extract the sequence string for each fastq read. I next iterate through the "in" set to see if the string has a Levenshtein distance of <=2 and pick the first "in" sequence that does.

The problem I have is that its very slow having a loop within a loop.

I there a way of speeding this up or a better way of mapping the function to the whole list of in strings and returning the best match?

```
# This part created a set of strings from infile
inlist = open("umi_tools_inlist_2000.txt", "r")
barcodes = []

for line in inlist:
    barcodes.append(line.split("\t")[0])

barcodes = set(barcodes)

# Next I iterate through two fastq files and extract the sequence of each read
with pysam.FastxFile("errors_fullbarcode_read_R1.fastq") as fh, pysam.FastxFile("errors_fullbarcode_read_R2.fastq") as fh2:

for record_fh, record_fh2  in zip(fh, fh2):
    barcode = record_fh.sequence[0:24]

    for b in barcodes:

        

        if Levenshtein.distance(barcode, b) <= 2:

            b = b + record_fh.sequence[24:]
            break
            
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: This may be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696859/how-do-i-use-kd-trees-for-determining-string-similarity , if you actually want to improve the quality of algo. 
Or if you change Levenshtein to more simple metrics you may involve kdtree directly to remove one of loops https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html. 
Or you can switch to a more performance language, c++, go.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look at cKDTree. Im also thinking C++ might be the best place to go next though.

Comment: Are there many calls to Levenshtein with the same two codes? If so you might be gain from caching those results using e.g.  `lru.cache` or by homegrown storing in a dictionary so you avoid recalculating the distance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary instead of list where keys will be barcodes.

If you don't like to use the loop in loop you can use list comprehension and test performance

```
inlist = open("umi_tools_inlist_2000.txt", "r")
barcodes = dict()

for line in inlist:
    barcodes[line.split("\t")[0]] = 0

# Next I iterate through two fastq files and extract the sequence of each read
with pysam.FastxFile("errors_fullbarcode_read_R1.fastq") as fh, pysam.FastxFile("errors_fullbarcode_read_R2.fastq") as fh2:

for record_fh, record_fh2  in zip(fh, fh2):
    barcode = record_fh.sequence[0:24]

    b_found = [b for b in barcodes.keys() if Levenshtein.distance(barcode, b) <= 2]
    # as per your logic b_found will have only zero or one ele
    if b_found:  
        new_b = barcodes[b_found[0]] + record_fh.sequence[24:]
        barcodes[new_b] = 0
        del barcodes[b_found[0]]
```